# Error when refreshing OLEDB connection - "Method Refresh of Object WorkbookConnection Failed"

Tags: excel, vba, oledbconnection

I'm experiencing an issue with a workbook I've created that has VBA code embedded to refresh an OLEDB connection to SQL Server.  This all works fine on computers with Excel 2013, but I have a user on Excel 2010 and it is not working on their computer.

The error message is:

```
"Run time error: '-2147417848 (80010108)': Method 'Refresh' of object 'WorkbookConnection' failed"
```

The code is:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("worksheet").OLEDBConnection
.Connection = Array( _
        "OLEDB;Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=User;Password=Password;Initial Catalog=InitialTable;Data Source=ServerName;" _
        , _
        "Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=A1234;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with " _
        , "column collation when possible=False")
.SavePassword = True
.CommandText = "select * from query"

ActiveWorkbook.Connections("worksheet").Refresh
End With
```

Any help or suggestions appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If the connection already exists, why reconfigure its connection string? Can the Excel 2010 user refresh the connection manually from the Data tab? If so, `ActiveWorkbook.Connections("worksheet").Refresh` should be all that's needed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Mathieu.   One of the reasons I have to configure the connection string is because I need to embed the password in VBA as I don't have the option to embed it within the normal "Connections" management within Excel Data tab itself (the save password option is disabled at my company).  

I will ask the user to test refreshing the connection manually though to see if that actually does work or not.

Comment: Use Windows Authentication and remove all passwords from connection strings then. Storing plain-text passwords in VBA code means that password is compromised. If your company has any real reason to forbid saving the password in the connection, then the password definitely doesn't belong in VBA code.